# adding background image in angularjs, css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I seem unable to apply style in css on element after using ng-style to setup background image.

HTML:

```
<body id="bg" ng-controller="BgImagesListController" ng-style="selBGImg">
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
    background: center center fixed transparent;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

JS:

```
var mlwcApp = angular.module('mlwcApp', [])
.controller('BgImagesListController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.selBGImg = {
        background : 'url(bgimgs/bg.jpg)'
    };
});
```

I used to setup background image in css and it worked. After using ng-style, the image can be shown but all other style gone. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change background to 'background-image':'url(bgimgs/bg.jpg)'

```js
var mlwcApp = angular.module('mlwcApp', [])
.controller('BgImagesListController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selBGImg = {
        'background-image' : 'url(https://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/images/thumb/e/ec/Das_Naggenvatcher.png/250px-Das_Naggenvatcher.png)'
    };

})
```

```css
[id="bg"] {
    background: center center fixed transparent;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body id="bg" ng-app="mlwcApp" ng-controller="BgImagesListController" ng-style="selBGImg">
    
</body>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you, but why background-image works here?

Comment: because you are overriding the background property and here you only change background-image.